# List of TFIDF points for Scikit Nearest Neighbor

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, nearest-neighbor

I can run kneighbors for one TFIDF but not for a list of them.

Before the details, I should mention the reason I am doing this is because running kneighbors for each data point is taking a very long time and I imagine giving kneighbors a list of points will be optimized internally.

Based on the NN documentation:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors

It says I can query for multiple points:

```
>>>X = [[0., 1., 0.], [1., 0., 1.]]
>>>neigh.kneighbors(X, return_distance=False) 
>>>array([[1],
   [2]]...)
```

I am trying to do the same.
I can run kneighbors for each point individually:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

samples = ["This is a test","a very good test","some more text"]
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(samples)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=-1) 
neigh.fit(X_train_tfidf)

ll=[]
test=["Test if this works","Zoom zoom"]
for k in test:
    predict = count_vect.transform([k])
    X_tfidf2 = tfidf_transformer.transform(predict)
    ll.append(X_tfidf2)
    res = neigh.kneighbors(X_tfidf2, return_distance=False)
#res = neigh.kneighbors(ll, return_distance=False)
```

When I add all the TFIDF sparse matrices to a list and try I get an error. Uncomment the last line to get error.

Error:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence (on the line res = neigh.kneighbors...)

Comment: can you please post some sample code that _actually_ runs?

Comment: I updated the post with demo data so it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
from scipy import sparse

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

samples = ["This is a test","a very good test","some more text"]
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(samples)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=-1) 
neigh.fit(X_train_tfidf)

ll=[]
test=["Test if this works","Zoom zoom"]
for k in test:
    predict = count_vect.transform([k])
    X_tfidf2 = tfidf_transformer.transform(predict)
    ll.append(X_tfidf2)

ll = sparse.vstack((ll))
res = neigh.kneighbors(ll, return_distance=False)
```

Without the loop:
    from scipy import sparse

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

samples = ["This is a test","a very good test","some more text"]
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(samples)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=-1) 
neigh.fit(X_train_tfidf)

test=["Test if this works","Zoom zoom"]
X_test_counts = count_vect.transform(test)

X_test_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_test_counts)

res = neigh.kneighbors(X_test_tfidf, return_distance=False)
```

Comment: When I try that I get:
ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices. X.shape[1] == 16 while Y.shape[1] == 8

Comment: It seems to work :) 
Testing the results to make sure they are the same and will accept answer!

Comment: @Sib you dont need to use the loop btw. see updated answer.

Comment: True! Thanks again.
Btw it runs much much faster now that all neighbors  are calculated at the same time !